# XRD-Amorphous materials

Tags: experimental-chemistry, x-ray-diffraction

I am interested in sealing some air-sensitive samples inside of xrd-amorphous material to allow for XRD and hopefully XRD-texturing analysis. Of course, Kapton is the common material used for this purpose, but I am unaware of a good way to seal two pieces of kapton together. Impulse sealers (ie [here](https://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/H-190/Poly-Bag-Sealers/Tabletop-Impulse-Sealer-12?pricode=WA9036&gadtype=pla&id=H-190&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjrHA3LOW3wIVkp-fCh3GSwu5EAQYASABEgIldPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)) are commonly used for creating plastic seals in food processing. However, they don't reach a high enough temperature to melt Kapton. I also tried to just heat the kapton with a soddering iron, to no avail. Are there other materials that maybe suitable for sample storage during xrd ?

Comment: More classically, glass was the choice.

Comment: Really, what type of glass?

Comment: See [this link](https://www.hilgenberg-gmbh.de/en/product-novelties/xrd-capillary-with-luer-connector/) for an example.

Comment: Not really sure since I never did that kind of a thing, and glass departments associated with chemistry departments aren’t a thing either. But in literature of the 50s and 60s there are lots of papers with distilling or otherwise getting samples into small tubes and crimping the glass shut. Great way to seal it. Best guess would be a standard boro-silicate glass with a reasonably low softening point.

Comment: In our department, we have glass capillaries for this. There are actually some suggestions for this from the Argonne beam-line here: https://wiki-ext.aps.anl.gov/ug11bm/index.php/Air_Sensitive_Samples

Comment: The other trick that I recently learned is that apparently thin packing tape also works, wherein the tape is 1-2 mil thick and the signal is either negligible or that it can be subtracted out.

Comment: PMMA (acrylic) may also be a good choice. It's used in the air-sensitive holder we bought from Bruker.